# Building a manual GridSearch (no CV!)

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search

I'm doing a tree-based regression model for time series data (the extrapolation problem would be solved by training a linear regression separately and then adding up those two models), but I'm struggling to find a solution to iterate through the parameters of my tree-based model. I can't use `GridSearchCV()` because would I would be incurring in data leakage as it's time series data. Hence, train and test will be fixed (e.g. train daily data in 2016-2017 range and test only 2018) then there would be no need for CV.

But still, I don't find a function that iterates through the parameters without CV, so I'm trying to create the code:

```
parameters = {'max_depth': [1,2,3],
                 'min_samples_leaf': [4,5,6],
                 'n_estimators': [7,8,9]}

iter_params = {}
for i in parameters.keys():
    iter_params[i] = parameters[i][0]
print(iter_params, '\n')

for k in parameters.keys():
    for p in parameters[k]:
        iter_params[k] = p
        print(iter_params)
        # IN THIS LINE WOULD GO FIT + PREDICT AND EVAL METRICS
```

**The first problem** is my code isn't able to iterate and print every possible combination. The first iteration must start with the first combination of `parameters`. The first `for` is to set up the `iter_params` in order to be able to iterate in the second `for`. I think the set up is needed because in the second `for` would go the `fit()` function which would need all the parameters that are different from the default. Also, I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way anyways.

**The second problem** is: I'm wondering, if it doesn't exist a function for this, maybe it's not a good approach? am I wrong here? My question is.. why?: If *(almost?)* nobody creates a tree-based model regressor in time series with a fixed train-test data window trying to iterate only the hyperparameters.. why would that be? I think that function doesn't exist because not many people need it.. but why?

Answer (score 0):

"Cross validation" techniques include the single train/test split, despite the recent trend to use it to mean specifically k-fold. `GridSearchCV` allows many different options for its `cv` parameter, including `TimeSeriesSplit` and `PredefinedSplit`, so that you can use still the convenience of `GridSearchCV`.

Python's `itertools` is probably the best choice of you want to iterate over combinations of lists manually.